# How can I use dependent select using Morphtoselect component in Filament PHP

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, laravel-filament

I want to create a dependent select where the value of another select field will be based on `morphtoselect` values (Model type and ID). But it seems reactive() method is not working on `morphtoselect` component.  And I don't know how to get the values from `morphtoselect` component. Anyone can help me?

I tried using reactive() to `morphtoselect` component and add closures callable `$set`(to `morphtoselect`) and get (to `$another` select) but seems not to be working.

```
return $form
            ->schema([
                MorphToSelect::make('payable')
                    ->label('Availment Classification')
                    ->types([
                        MorphToSelect\Type::make(Customer::class)->titleColumnName('name'),
                        MorphToSelect\Type::make(User::class)->titleColumnName('name')
                            ->modifyOptionsQueryUsing(fn (Builder $query) => $query->whereDoesntHave('customer')
                                        ->whereDoesntHave('roles.permissions', function ($query) {
                                            $query->where('id',36);
                                        })
                                    ),
                    ])
                    ->required()
                    ->preload()
                    ->searchable()
                    ->reactive()
                    ->afterStateUpdated(fn(callable $set)   =>   $set('payment_model_handle',null))
                    ->columnSpanFull(),
                Fieldset::make('Payment Model')
                    ->schema([
                        Select::make('payment_model_handle')
                            ->searchable()
                            ->columnSpanFull()
                            ->label('Payment Model')
                            ->relationship('AvailedPaymentModels','handle')
                            ->preload()
                            ->required()
                            ->options(function(callable $get, Closure $`your text`set){
                                $id = $get('payable'); //need to get the ID
                                $type = $set('payable'); //need to get the model type
                                $options = PaymentModel::whereDoesntHave('availedPaymentModels', function ($query) use($id,$type) {
                                    $query->where('payable_id', $id)
                                        ->where('payable_type', $type);
                                });
                            })
                    ])
            ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution in document
https://filamentphp.com/docs/2.x/forms/fields#dependant-selects

My Code Snippend Given below.

```html
Forms\Components\Select::make('game_match_team_id')
    ->options(
        $this->getMatchTeams($this->ownerRecord->id, 'selectbox')
    )
    ->searchable()
    ->preload()
    ->reactive()
    ->afterStateUpdated(fn (Set $set) => $set('club_member_id', null))
    ->required(),
Forms\Components\Select::make('club_member_id')
    ->options(
        function(Get $get) {
            $matchTeamId = $get('game_match_team_id');
            $matchTeam = GameMatchTeam::find($matchTeamId);
            if(! $matchTeam) {
                return [];
            }

            return $this->getTeamMembers($matchTeam->team->id);
        }
    )
    ->searchable()
    ->preload()
    ->reactive()
    ->required(),
```

**Note**
$this->getMatchTeams($this->ownerRecord->id, 'selectbox') and $this->getTeamMembers($matchTeam->team->id);

are just a trait function will return customized eloquent query result.